# Keep data in divs when comming back from other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

Firstly, I didn't know how to give a short description of the problem in the title, let me explain it here.

I'm creating social site, with all common features like/comments etc. Imagine Twitter/Instagram. I do have main/home page where all posts are displayed. Every post has a like button, so when it is clicked it triggers a AJAX function to send request to Django server to update the database with new like. This JS function also changes the style of the button, so user can know that he liked it. So far so good. Now when he decides that he want to comment this post, he clicks it and is redirected to the new page - the detail page. Here when the page is loading with data from server his like he gave earlier is visible(the div is red). All right, he commented, but know when pressing back button, in order to go to the home page, his like under the post is not more visible without reloading the page. I will demonstrate it using [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLr3D.jpg).

Now I'm using JS function to reload whole page, to get from Django server all new data, but I don't think it is good idea.

```js
<script>
    if (!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === 2) {
        // value 2 means "The page was accessed by navigating into the history"
        console.log('Reloading');
        window.location.reload(); // reload whole page
    }
</script>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This answer may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407